# Cannot instantiate class tests.LoginPageTest

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZZBM.png)    package tests;

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import junit.framework.Assert;
import pages.DashBoardPage;
import pages.LoginPage;
```

Here is the code for loginpageTest but it does not get instantiate. I feel like something is not instiliazed somewhere. When i run this app opens up but throws the error this test cannot be instatiated
    public class LoginPageTest extends LoginPage {

```
    //DashBoardPage dashBoardPage = new DashBoardPage(driver);


     public static WebDriver driver;
    LoginPage loginPage; 
    DashBoardPage ds;
     public LoginPageTest() { 
         super(driver); 
         ds=new DashBoardPage(driver);

         }


    @BeforeTest
    public void setup() throws MalformedURLException {

        intialization();
    }



    /*@Test(priority = 1)
    public void LoginPageTitleTest() {

        Assert.assertEquals(getPageTitle(), "verizon");

    }*/

    // 07/02/2019
    @Test(priority =2)
    public void VerizonlogoTest() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        try{
            if(UserID.isDisplayed())
            {
              clickUserID();
              clickPassword();
              clickLoginBtn();
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Clicking on I Agree Button");
        }
        finally{
            clickAgree();
        }
        explicitWait(ds.dashBoard);
        Assert.assertTrue(ds.getDashBoardTitle().equals("Dashboard"));
        /*driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@resource-id='USER']")).sendKeys("jomonli");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@resource-id='PASSWORD']")).sendKeys("Brownlenovo5@");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[@resource-id='btnLogin']")).isEnabled();
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[@text='Verizon Mobile Single Sign on']")).isDisplayed());
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[@text='First time user, click here to activate.']")).isEnabled());
        */
        //LoginPage loginPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
        //isElementVisible(loginPage.getVerizonLogo());
        //loginPage.clickUserID();

    }

    /*
     * @Test(priority = 2, description = "Logo is present Test") public boolean
     * VerizonLogoTest() { //boolean logo = loginPage.VerizonLogo();
     * //Assert.assertTrue(logo); //return logo; }
     * 
     * @Test(priority = 3, description = "LoginBtn is clickable and enabled")
     * public boolean LoginBtnClickableTest() { //boolean clickable =
     * loginPage.LoginBtnClickable(); //Assert.assertTrue(clickable); //return
     * clickable; }
     */

    //@Test(priority = 4, description = "User is able to login succesfully with valid credentials")
    public void LoginTest() {
        // dashBoardPage = loginPage.Login(prop.getProperty("userID"),
        // prop.getProperty("password"));
    }

    /*
     * @Test(description = "FirstTimeUserLink is clickable and enabled") public
     * boolean FirstTimeUserLinkClickableTest() { boolean clickable =
     * loginPage.FirstTimeUserLinkClickable(); Assert.assertTrue(clickable);
     * return clickable; }
     */

    @AfterTest
    public void teardown() {

        driver.quit();
}


//  private Object () {
//      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      return null;
//  }
}
```

Here is the code for loginpageTest but it does not get instantiate. I feel like something is not instiliazed somewhere. When i run this app opens up but throws the error this test cannot be instatiated

======================================================================

```
BASE PAGE
package base;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class BaseClass {

    public static Properties prop;

    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static URL url;

    public static WebDriver intialization() {


        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

        cap.setCapability("deviceName", "Galaxy Tab S3");// setting > about
                                                            // phone
        cap.setCapability("udid", "624258263526a1e8");
        // udid is the device name when you press - cmd adb devices
        cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.0.0");
        cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.verizon.launcher.sdnasit");
        cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.verizon.launcher.webview.WebActivity");
        // cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "Apk file location
        // C:\\apkfiles\\AndroidUI.apk"
        cap.setCapability("noReset", "True");
        cap.setCapability("automationName", "uiautomator2");

        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 60);

        // any application will have app package and app activity
        // download apk info from playstore
        try{

             url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        driver = new AndroidDriver(url, cap);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //LoginPageTest loginPage= new LoginPageTest();

        return driver;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be your device don`t on **Debug Mode**.
(Check your phone tools => *Additional settings* => *For developers* => *Debug Mode*(Or "*Debug by USB*") => Switch On)